# fasten or skip webpack bundling in development

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, gulp

I have to wait at least 30 seconds when I save a file, I used gulp watch and webpack. The problem is I have hundred files that require webpack's bundling. How to fasten the build process?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup you could use a `--watch` option or convert the build to use `webpack-dev-server` in general you should use partial rebuilds in development. If you use asset hashing disable that in development for increased performance.

More info https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html